# AngularJS searching by nested data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new to AngularJS.  I am trying to get a simple search based on the users name, which in my case is not stored on the top most layer.  Here is the example:

```
<div ng-init="users = [
{'fields':{'name':'Mary Brown','person_nickname':'M'},'username':'mbrown'},
{'fields':{'name':'John Smith','person_nickname':'J-Dog'},'username':'jsmith'}]">
</div>
```

[Here is the plnkr that searches all the fields](http://plnkr.co/edit/9OFKBJrLlfsu0LsMGouZ?p=preview)  I want to take this and make it such that it only searches `fields.name`.  In this plunker, I could type "dog" and still get the second user returned, which is not what I want.

I tried changing my input ng-model to `search.fields.name` but when I do that, the search doesn't activate at all.  I can type in any string into the text box and nothing is filtered out.

What am I missing?  Thank you!

EDIT:
Full code since plunker is currently down:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="App">
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0-rc.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div ng-init="users = [
      {'fields':{'name':'Mary Brown','person_nickname':'M'},'username':'mbrown'},
      {'fields':{'name':'John Smith','person_nickname':'J-Dog'},'username':'jsmith'}]">
    </div>    

    Name only <input ng-model="search.fields"><br>

    <table id="userTable">
      <tr ng-repeat="user in users | filter:search">
        <td>{{user}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>    

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plnkr is not running right now, but if you have an ng-repeat which you want to filter, then look at the official docs, especially upvoted comments are useful: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:filter

> item in myArray | filter:{propertyThatWillBeFiltered: value}

If you are talking about searching inside your model, then you should use ["filter"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/javascript-how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes) method on an array.

Comment: I added the code above.  I am using an ng-repeat but I'm trying to figure out what the filter value would be.  The example in the angular documentation assumes that the data is on the top level and I just can't get it to work with the users data structure

Comment: I have forked and modified your plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/Wj4cUS?p=preview there you can exactly see how to write the filter expression.